# Variables inside protocols in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Why is there a provision to include a variable inside a protocol declaration, when is this ever used.

```
@protocol SampProtocol
int i;
- (void)func;
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't any such provision. clang issues an error if you try to compile that code; gcc considers the `int i;` statement as part of the parent scope (which is probably a bug).